# Fragment is reloaded after getting a result from camera onActivityResult

Tags: android, camera, fragment, onactivityresult

Android Fragment is reloaded after getting a result from select camera or gallery onActivityResult while using Micromax Q424 in 5.1 version.in other mobiles working but in Micromax Q424 is reloaded the fragment. how avoid after getting results.

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you granted the permission required for using camera, runtime permission are also required along with manifest permissions.

```
public boolean CheckPermissionForWriteStorage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

use above code for taking permission 
and below code in onACtivityResult

```
 final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            isCamera = true;
                        } else {
                            isCamera = action.equalsIgnoreCase(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isCamera) {
                    String selectedImagePath = getImagePath();

                    aQuery.id(imgFarmerPhoto).image(selectedImagePath);
                } else {
                    String selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                    selectedImagePath = getRightAngleImage(selectedImagePath);
                    aQuery.id(imgFarmerPhoto).image(selectedImagePath);
                }
```